# How to write UDAF in hive with multiple arguments

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I want to write a UDAF in hive which can take more then one arguments.
Below is few class code architecture, in which I have remove the actual logics in methods as that will just take space

```
public class CountWithRating extends UDAF{

    public static class MovieCountWithGivenRating implements UDAFEvaluator{
        public static class PartialClass{
            Set users;
            Map movieMap; // contains movieIds , number of users which give the eq or more then given rating
        }
        private PartialClass partial;

        public void init(){
            partial = null;
        }

        public boolean iterate(IntWritable userId,IntWritable movieId,Text rating,DoubleWritable static_rating){

        }

        public PartialClass terminatePartial(){
            return partial;
        }


        public boolean merge(PartialClass other){
            return true;
        }


        public IntWritable terminate(){

        }

    }

}
```

In this I create the function in hive as below

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION MaxMovieCount AS 'hive.udaf.CountWithRating';
```

and call the function as below

```
select MaxMovieCount(userId,movieId,rating,4.0) from rating;
```

but it give error as below

```
FAILED: NoMatchingMethodException No matching method for class hive.udaf.CountWithRating with (int, int, string, double). Possible choices: _FUNC_(int, int, string, struct)
```